# IndexOf returns -1 if the string contains "\"

Tags: c#, string, indexof, operation

i have a `string code= "\0\u0001\0\0\0????\u0001\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\u000f\u0001\0\0\0\u001f\u0001\\ABC01\0\0\0\u001f\0\0\0\u0002\DEF\01\0\0\0\u001f\0\0\0\u0003\\\GHI01\0\0\0\u001f\0\0\0"`

i need to retrieve the data between u0001 and u0002 and u0002 and u0003 and so on.

Output as:

> ABC,DEF, GHI etc.

How i'm trying to achieve it :

```
code.Substring((code.IndexOf("\u000" + i) + ("\u000" + i).Length), code.IndexOf("\u000" + (i + 1)) - code.IndexOf("\u000" + i) - ("\u000" + i).Length));
```

This results in compilation error :

> Unrecognised escape sequence.

I have tried `code.IndexOf("\u0001")`, this works but not `code.IndexOf("\u000"+i)`.

How to solve?

EDIT: Many of you seem to have gotten the question wrong,so here is the complete code:

private static List RetriveMethod( )

```
    {            
         input="\u0001\0\u0005\0\0\0\u0001\0\0\0\tMyMethod1\u0001\u001cfunction MyMethod1("there cud be another function by name function here" ) {\n\t\n\n}\0\0\0\0\u0002\0\0\0\tMyMethod2\u0001?\u0001function MyMethod2( ) { }\0\0\0\0\u0003\0\0\0\tMyMethod3\u0001Ofunction MyMethod3( ) 

        List<string> ExtactedMethods = new List<string>();
        for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
        {
            ExtactedMethods.Add(code.Substring((code.IndexOf("\u000" + i) + ("\u000" 
            + i).Length), code.IndexOf("\u000" + (i + 1)) - 
             code.IndexOf("\u000" + i) - ("\u000" + i).Length));
           }

        return ExtactedMethods;
    }
```

Comment: i cant understand your question

Comment: Replace \ with \\

Comment: @Agent_Orange Well Agent_Orange, I have not see you for a while

Comment: Check my post ;-)

Comment: What you expect from `"\u000" + i` is really just `(char) i`. And `"\u000" + (i + 1)` is `(char) (i + 1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\u----` denotes Unicode character (hence the prefix `u`). `"\u000"` is invalid Unicode character and that causes compilation error.

If you want `\u` not to be treated as Unicode character, than escape `\` character

```
"\\u"
```

Suggested Fix by @Immersive to escape `\u` in source string

```
string code= @"\0\u0001\...."
```

Read more about [verbatim string literals](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/strings.html)

Comment: @Atom99 Because in the initial string you have `"\u0001"` not `"\\u0001"`

Comment: Agreed.  The initial issue would appear to be your search string.  Escaped characters are evaluated at compile time, thus `"\u000" + i` is compiled into `<invalid symbol> + i`.  If you change your search string to un-escaped codes, `"\\u000"` then you must also do that to the source string.  The easiest way is to declare the string as a literal (note the "@"), ie `string code = @"\0\u00..."`

Comment: The _better_  fix is to use @Evk's suggestion from the comments on your OP, and search for `(char) i`

Comment: @Immersive Thanks, Clear explanation. In fact, i don't suggest any *fix* to the problem, i just wanted to explain the cause of the error.

Answer (score 1):

> Note: code.IndexOf ("\ u000" + i) does not work because you can not convert an integer to a string, and what IndexOf does is find the numeric position of that character in the string, instead you should try code.IndexOf ( "\ u000") + i where are you this is the correct way to add a value to the position (value returned by IndexOf), if that is your goal
>
> You can not use the backslash \ because it is an escape sequence character \ n \ r \ t, if you want to apply it, you must add two \\ where the IDE will interpret that the first is the escape sequence and the second the character to read

In any case, I have created this method that extracts the uppercase letters of your text string

```
public List<string> GetUpperLetters(string input)
        {
            List<string> result = new List<string>();
            int index_0 = 0;
            string accum = string.Empty;

            //Convert string input to char collection 
            //and walk it one by one
            foreach (char c in input.ToCharArray())
            {
                if(char.IsLetter(c) && char.IsUpper(c))
                {
                    accum += c;
                    index_0++;
                    if(index_0 == 3)
                    {
                        index_0 = 0;
                        result.Add(accum);
                        accum = string.Empty;
                    }
                }
            }

            return result;
        }
```

where

> GetUpperLetters(code)[index from zero to n]

```
string code= "\0\u0001\0\0\0????\u0001\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\u000f\u0001\0\0\0\u001f\u0001\\ABC01\0\0\0\u001f\0\0\0\u0002\DEF\01\0\0\0\u001f\0\0\0\u0003\\\GHI01\0\0\0\u001f\0\0\0";

GetUpperLetters(code)[0] returns ABC
GetUpperLetters(code)[1] returns DEF
GetUpperLetters(code)[2] returns GHI
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot all of you for the suggested answers. 
The one by @Immersive worked!
The change to be done is string code= @"\0\u0001\0\0\0????\u0001\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\u000f\u0001\0\0\0\u001f\u0001\ABC01\0\0\0\u001f\0\0\0\u0002\DEF\01\0\0\0\u001f\0\0\0\u0003\\GHI01\0\0\0\u001f\0\0\0"
and

code.Substring((code.IndexOf(@"\u000" + i) + (@"\u000" + i).Length), code.IndexOf(@"\u000" + (i + 1)) - code.IndexOf(@"\u000" + i) - (@"\u000" + i).Length));